# Strings containing ".com" are automatically being substituted for ".(class)"

Tags: string, google-apps-script

Whenever I have a String containing the term ".com.br" (ex.: "google.com.br") the string I get have the ".com.br" substituted for ".(class)".

Example Code:

```
    function myFunction() {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
      var data = new String('google.com.br')
}
```

the value of data afterwards is "google.(class)" as shown in the debug window below
[debug window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gPsw.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["com.au" string is displayed as "(class)" in Script Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52231226/com-au-string-is-displayed-as-class-in-script-editor)

Answer (score 0):

I ran this:

```
function watthef() 
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = new String('google.com.br');
  Logger.log(data);//[17-10-26 17:17:35:558 MDT] google.com.br
}
```

and the view logs returned: google.com.br