# "com.au" string is displayed as "(class)" in Script Editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I need to store an Australian domain as a string. Australian domains end with ".com.au"

Google Scripts seems to be displaying all instances of ".com.au" with "(class)".

To reproduce, create a basic function in Google Apps Scripts as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = "com.au";
  console.log("x: " + x);
  var z = 1;   //<--create break point here
}
```

Create a breakpoint at `var z = 1`, and then debug the script.

**Actual Results:**

In the console (at breakpoint):

```
x: (class)
```

**Expected Results:**

```
x: "com.au"
```

*Note: upon further testing, from a practical perspective, "(class)" seems to still be treated as "com.au" so this is not a blocker to use, but it is odd and does not help when debugging.

Comment: Do you get that same issue if you are parsing input, e.g. if cell A1 on a Google Sheet is `com.au`, do you get this same behavior when you read cell A1 into a variable?

Comment: @tehhowch, yes, same behavior.

Comment: And same from a Ui prompt / Browser inputBox?

Comment: @Rubén, I investigated further and it the string change is only cosmetic, and from a practical application, doesn't change the end result. I added more detailed steps to replicate regardless.

Comment: I suppose that's how the JS code parser in the Google Script Editor is written. There isn't much you can do about it other than reporting it to Google as an issue.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. But in my case this isn't only cosmetic. When I concatenate the value it appears as ".(class)" as well. Did anybody manage to work it around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was reported as a bug to Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114358543

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a bug of the Google Apps Script editor debugger that should be reported to Google. Please follow the directions on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#bugs.

Comment: Yep, already done. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/114358543. Thank you for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

I just got around this bug with the use of an Array.

```
function myFunction() {
  var array = new Array();
  var text ="email@email.com.br";
  array[0] = string; 
}
```

text returns `email@email.(class)`

`array[0]` returns `email@email.com.br`

Comment: `var text` but `= string`?